# Understanding Async Control Flow with Promises, Generators and Async/Await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, generator

I have read several stackoverflow posts, blog posts and Nodejs Design Patterns book in order to gain a better understanding of async control flow. Now, I am comfortable writing regular callback passing style (CPS) code. However, I was trying to get out of the habit and improve readability of my code (or, avoid "callback hell"). My problem is, I seem to understand `Promise`, `Generator` and `Async/Await` as individual concepts and how to use them. However, I am not sure how to take advantage of them to convert CPS functions to have no nesting.

To help understand the concept, I wrote the following snippet:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const bluebird = require('bluebird');
const path = require('path');

// promisified fns
const readFile = bluebird.promisify(fs.readFile);
const readStat = bluebird.promisify(fs.stat);

function* tasks() {
    let fileLocation = path.resolve(__dirname, 'package.json');
    yield readFile(fileLocation, 'utf8');
    yield readStat(fileLocation);
}

(async () => {
    const taskRunner = tasks();
    let fileContent = await taskRunner.next().value;
    let fileStat = await taskRunner.next().value;

    console.log(`Content: ${fileContent}`);
    console.log(`Stats: ${fileStat}`);
})();
```

The snippet runs and I get the result I expected. My questions are:

1. Is this the "right" approach or is this overkill (promises + generators + async/await)?
2. Can this be achieved simply?

If possible, I would be glad if I'm pointed to some resources that explains the scenario and approaches in an easy to understand manner.

Comment: I see no need for a generator there. Why not just `await` each `Promise`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think I understand your point. I removed the generator and the output is what I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(async () => {

    let fileContent = await readFile(fileLocation, 'utf8');
    let fileStat = await readStat(fileLocation);

    console.log(`Content: ${fileContent}`);
    console.log(`Stats: ${fileStat}`);
})();
```

No need for generator

Generators are used to explain the concept of async/await because it's a combination of the two.
But to use async/await function you don't need them anymore

Comment: or `let [fileContent, fileStat] = await Promise.all( readFile(fileLocation, 'utf8'), readStat(fileLocation) );` if you want to start both async operations at once, instead of waiting for readFile to resolve before calling readStat.

Comment: @Paulpro Just wondering wouldn't this lead to a race condition since, both functions are trying to access the same file?

Comment: @AbrarHossain That's possible. It depends on if you need the readStat results to reflect the recent file access. If you fo then you do need to wait for the readFile Promise to resolve first.